# How do I add a rollup column to my protfolio backlog

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

The release notes for Sprint 157 announced that it is possible to add rollup columns.

How can I add these rollup columns to my backlog?

[Our Organization page looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xlqv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sprint 157 not yet enable on Azure DevOps, other features which are mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/pipelines/sprint-157-update) not exist and also you can find this info:

> These features will roll out over the next two to three weeks.

In the organization page you can see only what new on sprint 156:

[image]

Comment: In our organization board there is Sprint 157 release notes above the Organization settings

Comment: @IMayr Interesting, but in the line I provided Microsoft say "there feature will roll out over the next two or three weeks" so I guess that are not available yet.

Comment: I thought it was already released because of the info on the org page and on the release notes there haven't been an hint for the release date. Thanks a lot

Comment: @IMayr You're welcome! you can accept the answer :)